# Importing a gif as an animation does not work in Mathematica 10.4

Tags: import, animation, gif-format

This code

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPp7l.gif","Animation"]
```

causes Mathematica 10.4 consume ever more memory, without showing the animation. It works in Mathematica 11.

Is there a workaround? Alternatively, can you please tell me how to use `Animate` to make something similar to that?

Comment: We can't possibly know what initialization cells you have in your notebook. If it is related to that, then it's not something we can debug.

Comment: @C.E. The error is in that import: if I comment it, everything works fine.

Comment: ok, I understand now. The thing about initialization cells wasn't necessary for the question, it is enough to just evaluate that single line of code to show what the problem is. I have reproduced it in 10.4, and have also confirmed that it works in 11. If you don't like my edit you can always change it back, I think it is clearer what the problem is this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `Import` that was fixed in Mathematica 11. To get the same output in Mathematica 10.4, we might use

```
frames = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPp7l.gif"];
ListAnimate[frames]
```